# update_all with string concatenate

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, update-all

I'm trying to update the 'allowed_ips' field for all my users, but it's not working as I expect.

'allowed_ips' is a string with ip-addresses.

```rb
User.where(role: 1).update_all(:allowed_ips => ["CONCAT('allowed_ips', '192.168.0.1')"])

# output:
> user.allowed_ips
 => "CONCAT('allowed_ips', '192.168.0.1')"
```

What I want is:

```sql
UPDATE 'users' SET 'allowed_ips' = CONCAT('allowed_ips', '192.168.0.1') WHERE 'role' = '1'
```

```rb
# output:
> user.allowed_ips
 => "127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.2, 192.168.0.1"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
User.where(role: 1).update_all(["allowed_ips = CONCAT(allowed_ips, ?)", '192.168.0.1'])
```

In your case "CONCAT..." is considered to be just a string value for the updated field.

BTW, you probably need to fix the CONCAT call itself as well, or the strings will be glued together without the delimiters.

Also check `serialize` ([link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-serialize)) for storing objects (arrays for example) in the ActiveRecord model attributes. This might be a cleaner way to get what you want to achieve

Comment: Thank you! This works: User.where(role: 1).update_all("allowed_ips = CONCAT(allowed_ips, 'new_ip')")

Comment: how can this be done by also checking if the concatenated value is already there in the string or not , if its there then don't concatenate and if it isn't then do.

Answer (score 1):

The CONCAT should not be in quotes. The allowed_ips inside CONCAT should not be in quotes.

```
User.where(role: 1).update_all("'allowed_ips' = CONCAT(allowed_ips, ', 192.168.0.1')")
```